# Angular Material using sidenav and toolbar as re-usable components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use the Angular Materials components to create re-usable components for an entire app. I am trying to click the menu button on the material tool bar and have it open the material sidenav.  I created a button in the app component body to trigger the sidenav, and that works, but I am getting a compile error when I try to do the same thing from the toolbar button click.

The error is: **Error: src/app/toolbar/toolbar.component.html(6,9): Property 'sidenav' does not exist on type 'ToolbarComponent'.**

*I think I need to be able to reference sidenav from **app.component**, but I do not know how to do this.*

I know I can move all of the toolbar code to the AppComponent, but then I can't break these items out into individual components for reuse.

I would appreciate any feedback or help with this.

Here is the file structure.
In my demo tests I broke out the toolbar and sidenav into their own directories like this:
src
-app
--sidenav
--toolbar
--home
--dashboard
-- (..and otherContent Dirs... )

**src\app\app.module.ts** looks like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { MaterialModules } from './material-module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ToolbarComponent } from "./toolbar/toolbar.component";
import { SidenavComponent } from './sidenav/sidenav.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LangListComponent } from "./lang-list/langlist.component";
  ... other component imports ...

import { RedColorDirective } from "./red-color.directive";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // localhost
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: "dashboard",  // localhost/dashboard
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    SidenavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LangListComponent,
    
    RedColorDirective,
  ],

  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), BrowserModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MaterialModules],

  providers: [],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

All material modules are imported in the file: **src\app\material-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { MatSidenavModule } from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import { MatToolbarModule } from "@angular/material/toolbar";

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatIconModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModules {}
```

**src\app\app.components.ts**  looks like this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  opened: boolean;

}
```

**src\app\app.component.html**  looks like:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" [(opened)]="opened">
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>

    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
    <div align="center">
      <h1 redColored>Understanding Angular</h1>
    </div>
    <button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">sidenav.toggle()</button>
    <h2> Router Views </h2>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**src\app\toolbar\toolbar.component.ts** looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.css']
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  lightMenu = false;

  invertMenuColor() {
    this.lightMenu = !this.lightMenu;
    console.log("LightMenu: " + this.lightMenu);
  }

}
```

and the **src\app\toolbar\toolbar.component.html** looks like this:

```
<p>
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button mat-icon-button 
        class="example-icon menu-icon" 
        aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon"
        (click)="sidenav.toggle()"
      >
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
      <span style="display: block; text-align: center">Company Logo Here</span>
      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
      
      <button mat-icon-button
        class="example-icon color-icon"
        aria-label="Example icon-button with color choice icon"
        (click)="invertMenuColor()"
      >
        <mat-icon>invert_colors</mat-icon>
      </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
</p>
```

Comment: I don't see the imported `MatSidenavModule` in your `app.module.ts`. The same as any other Angular Material modules.

Comment: it's imported in the MaterialModules file. I can add that if it helps.